# Increase view width from right to left

Tags: android, android-view

In these days, I'm working on an application and I have to add a view which has to show air flow from right to left and air-flow-width has to change from right to left side. This is my xml code for object;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exfan_status"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/green" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exfan_battery"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/if_battery_empty" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exfan_link"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ethernet_off" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exfan"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/fan" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exfan_flow"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:background="@mipmap/exfan_flow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_setting"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/setting_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my java code for this object;

```
public class ViewExhaustFan extends RelativeLayout {

    public ViewExhaustFan(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public ViewExhaustFan(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        ImageView rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.object_exhaust_fan, this);
        ImageView img_exfan = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_exfan);
        ImageView img_exfan_link = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_exfan_link);
        ImageView img_exfan_status = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_exfan_status);
        ImageView img_exfan_flow = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_exfan_flow);
        ImageView img_exfan_battery = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_exfan_battery);

        ImageView img_setting = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_setting);

        changeFlowSize(img_exfan_flow, -100);
        //changeFlowSize(img_exfan_flow, 100);
    }

    public void changeFlowSize(ImageView image, int size){
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = size;
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

I tried negative values to change air-flow image from right to left but it didn't work. What should I do to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: increase width as well as right margin.

Comment: Because you set the fix width of relativelayout.

Comment: @Abhay Koradiya I did it too, but it moves whole the view

Comment: remove Fix Width.

Comment: @Abhay Koradiya I set width to wrap-content but If i want to move air-flow image to left I have to move other obects to right. I put other objects in another layout to make it easy. Thanks. I'm gonna test scale and translation animation too.

Answer (score 0):

i was have the same problem but at the end I solve it like so :

1. I put my ViewGroup which i want to move in ConstraintLayout.
2. set the constraints of the ViewGroup to top and left.
3. when you want to increase width from right just increase width , and when left increase width and decrease left margin.